# how to get multiple-part-substing from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am trying to get multiple part of a string as new string for my project "it is part of fql", I have this string example:

```
{"data": [{"text":"how can you get in"},{"text": "this is amazing..."},{"text": "this is another example"}, {"text":"let, this one be the last example and thanks you..."}]}
```

I want to get new string as :

```
how can you get in this is amazing this is another example let this one be the last example and thanks you
```

another example:

```
{"data": [{"text":"how can you get in"}]}
```

new string:

```
how can you get in
```

another one:

```
{"data": []}
```

new string: **new string should be empty for this one.**

note: above examples can be any size and any length.

thank you.

Comment: Please show your code and explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: Step one would be to parse this string as Json. See the excellent [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library.

Comment: Get a JSON parser, let it build an object for you and loop through the string results and build your string.

Comment: Any size *and* any length? Wow. Anyway, that looks like JSON. Find an appropriate library?

Comment: so far I couldn't solve this because it comes in different length, but I can get text without char using: var stringArray = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', ':', '-', '"', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\n', '\t', ';', '\'', '\\', '/' });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
var anon = new { data = new[] { new { text = "" } } };
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anon);
var text = String.Join(" ", obj.data.Select(x=>x.text));
```

or

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var text = String.Join(" ", jobj["data"].Select(x=>x["text"]));
```